# Problema com ArrayList

Tags: java, array

Estou aprendendo sobre Array e estou quebrando a cabeça com este código, alguém pode me explicar porque ele não esta funcionando?

Aparece este erro

> The type List is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with
>   arguments

nesta linha   `List<Integer> lista = new ArrayList<Integer>();`

```
package DeclaracaoArray;

import java.awt.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class Declaracao_Array {


    public int sorteia(){
            List<Integer> lista = new ArrayList<Integer>() ;

            lista.add ( "Alice" ) ;
            lista.add ( "Bruno" ) ;
            lista.add ( "Carlos" ) ;
            lista.add ( "Daniel" ) ;

   Collections.shuffle ( lista ) ;

       // pega qualquer indice. pegamos o primeiro para conveniencia.

       return (( Integer ) lista.get ( 0 )).intValue () ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Não edite a pergunta dessa forma, você mudou completamente o que foi perguntado anteriormente e agora parece que as respostas postadas não fazem sentido. Se aquele problema foi resolvido, marque a resposta correta e então crie uma nova pergunta para tratar desse novo erro que está tendo.

Comment: @renan o problema como um todo (com o arraylist) continua Renan, só mudou a mensagem de erro, por isso não criei outra pergunta.

Comment: O primeiro problema era por você estar importando o objeto `List` do pacote errado. Agora é porque sua classe não possui um método `main`.

Comment: Entendi @renan, vou fechar esta pergunta, obrigado!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você importou o pacote errado:

```
import java.awt.List;
```

Quando na verdade era para ser:

```
import java.util.List;
```

Como pode-se ver na documentação o [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/List.html) que você usou não faz uso dos genéricos, enquanto o [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) que você queria usar sim.

Comment: Alterei o import e mudei também para List<String> lista = new ArrayList<String>(); e agora o erro esta no Return The method intValue() is undefined for the type String

Comment: Se você adicionou Strings a sua lista seu método deve retornar String e não mais int, assim: `public String sorteia(){` e o return fica assim: `return lista.get ( 0 );`

Answer (score 5):

Você está definindo que a lista vai conter variáveis do tipo `Integer` enquanto você está preenchendo com variáveis do tipo `String` que são os nomes.

Se você não vai adicionar um valor que o tipo seja diferente de `String` declare a variável da lista dessa maneira:

```
List lista = new ArrayList();
```

Ou

```
List<String> lista = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Comment: continua aparecendo o mesmo erro: The type List is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <String>

Comment: Mude o import como de awt para util como foi mencionado pelo Math, o que falei agora vai te ajudar daqui a pouco quando você tiver arrumado a importação (;

Comment: Alterei o import e mudei também para List<String> lista = new ArrayList<String>(); e agora o erro esta no Return  The method intValue() is undefined for the type String

Comment: Agora não vai retornar mais um Integer, mas sim uma String, isso já deve resolver: `return lista.get(0)`. E altere o `public int sorteia()` para `public String sorteia()`

Comment: Desculpa encher tanto o saco com isso, mas como estou aprendendo estou quebrando a cabeça rs Fiz as alterações e o novo erro é no momento da execução agora:          O método principal não foi encontrado na classe DeclaracaoArray.Declaracao_Array; defina o método principal como:
   public static void main(String[] args)
Vou alterar a pergunta com o novo código.

Comment: @PauloRoberto você precisa declarar o método main da forma que o erro está mostrando: `public static void main(String[] args)`, entretanto perceba que sua dúvida foi mudando do longo do tempo e as respostas ficam desatualizadas, sendo que se alguém chegar no tópico agora vai achar que nós respondedores somos loucos, pois nossas respostas já não mais respondem a pergunta :)

Comment: @Math Entendi, foi mal.